# Theme Bootstrap and Jhipster

Tags: bootstrap-4, jhipster

it's possibile to integrate an external bootstrap theme (downloaded from themeforest.net) into Jhipster?
If yes, what is the best practice to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JHipster (e.g. v6.5.1) already comes with Bootstrap, as you can find in `package.json`:

```
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "5.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1"
```

And all a bootstrap-theme ought to need are the bootstrap libraries (css/js), but it depends on your external theme, if there are some other libraries to load.

Therefore you can integrate the code into the Angular components in `src/main/webapp/[...]`.

Perhaps you can build your own JHipster blueprint as mentioned in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gg5CYoBdpVo (JHipster Conf 2019 : JHipster side-by-side in practice by David Steiman).

Also - beside all of the documentation that can be found on https://www.jhipster.tech - [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRyDJC1Ff0M) ("The new Voxxed websites using JHipster, Angular and GitLab by Stephan Janssen") helped me a lot.

Don't stop, don't care for downvotes. You will learn a lot more important things to be able to shape "the web" along with JHipster best-practice approach. At least I do and am very thankful for the absolute pro's behind JHipster sharing their time and knowledge.